# Can't install onnxruntime

Tags: python, pip, onnxruntime

I want to install the onnxruntime pip library but i have this output:

`pip install onnxruntime ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement onnxruntime (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for onnxruntime`

Also:

`pip install onnxruntime-gpu ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement onnxruntime-gpu (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for onnxruntime-gpu`

links:

[`onnxruntime-gpu` at PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/onnxruntime-gpu/)

[`onnxruntime` at PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/onnxruntime/)

[`onnxruntime` at Github](https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime)

My python version is 3.9
My OS is Windows 11 (I already have the VSC Built Tools)
My pip version is 23.1.2.

I want to install this library because is a requirement to use As-One a library for object detection.
https://github.com/augmentedstartups/AS-One

Answer (score 0):

Typically that error is due to using an unsupported python version, however there are builds for python 3.9 as you can see here with the 'cp39' packages: https://pypi.org/project/onnxruntime-gpu/#files

There are only 64-bit builds though so wondering if you have a 32-bit version of Windows installed.